# How resolve a non-numeric value encountered?=

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have these two problems when I updated the plugins.

These the messages it is showing me:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/jacqueline/fw/core/core.reviews.php on line 210

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'class' in /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/jacqueline/shortcodes/trx_basic/section.php on line 154

Thank you

Comment: This appears to be a [purchased theme](https://themeforest.net/item/jacqueline-spa-massage-salon-theme/17101639), so my recommendation would be to see if they have any updates or offer support

Comment: Which is the current PHP version of the website?

Comment: `I updated the plugins` is a pretty wide scope in coding, even limited to wordpress it is too wide for anyone to be able to help. Open the code and see what it does, or contact the developer.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. That´s true, it is a purchased theme that has been giving me such a headache because it does not offer any regular updates. The current php version of the website is 7.4.28.

Comment: Since these are both warnings, not errors, for now you should be able to disable WP_DEBUG to silence them. It is not a good solution, but it should at least work for the time being.